# Python Dictionary and Loop

Tags: python, loops

How do I loop through a dictionary in Python?

I am trying to loop through a dictionary in Python, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. Here's what I've tried:

```
my_dict = {"apple": 1, "banana": 2, "orange": 3}

for item in my_dict:
    print(item)
```

I was expecting this code to print out the keys of the my_dict dictionary ("apple", "banana", and "orange"), but instead it only prints out the keys without their associated values:

```
apple
banana
orange
```

How can I modify my code to loop through the dictionary and print out both the keys and their associated values? Thank you.

Comment: Well you never tried to get the value...

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over my_dict is equivalent to iterating over its keys, you can iterate over both by iterating over my_dict.items()

```
my_dict = {"apple": 1, "banana": 2, "orange": 3}

for key, val in my_dict.items():
    print(f'{key}: {val}')
```